# Field Collections Arrays

Tags: entities

I have done my due diligence, but can't find an answer anywhere. I am trying to pop an array in a field collection and then implode it. Here is my code, which is not working. Also, I am not sure if this is the way to use count. Any help appreciated.

```
/**
* Implements template_preprocess_entity().
*/
function mytheme_preprocess_entity(&$variables, $hook) {

$function = 'mytheme_preprocess_' . $variables['entity_type'];
if (function_exists($function)) {
$function($variables, $hook);
    }
}

/**
* Field Collection-specific implementation of template_preprocess_entity().
*/
function mytheme_preprocess_field_collection_item(&$variables) {

// Return a comma separated list of donors
if ($variables['view']->current_display != 'bookplates_landing_page') {
if ($variables['#field_name'] == 'field_collection_donor') {
}
// nothing below here works
// render text for single donor
if (count($variables['row']->field_field_collection_donor) == 1) {
      $variables['output'] = $variables['#field_name']->last_render_text;
}
else {
// get all the donors
$donors = array();
foreach ($variables['row']->field_field_collection_donor as $donor) {
$donors[] = $donor['raw']['safe_value'];
}
// append the last donor with an "and" before it
$donor_last = array_pop($donors);
$variables['output'] = implode(', ', $donors) . " and " . $donor_last;
         }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You're trying to count your condition which makes no sense. Basically you're doing this `count( 1 == 1);`  O_O According to the php manuall [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) is used to count all elements in an array, or something in an object.